# Impact of master node and etcd failure in a k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I want to understand what could be the possible impact of a master node failure in a k8s cluster with only one master node with internal etcd store.

As per my understanding, all kinds of deployed workload containers (including stateless and stateful sets with persistent volume claims) running on worker nodes would keep on running until recreation of any container is required as they don't have a direct functional dependency on the master node and etcd store for their core functions. And, the unavailability of the master node only affects the control plane operations for the cluster.

Is my understanding correct? If not, could you please explain the impact of the master node failure on my workload running on that cluster?

I understand that the best way to achieve HA for k8s cluster is to set up a multi-master cluster with possibly externalizing etcd stores also for decoupling of them. This question is to understand the exact impact of the master node failure to take an informed call before configuring a multi-master cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Etcd operators on the quorum system so as long as the cluster sees a majority it will continue operating. If the failed node was the current leader, the others would trigger an election after the heartbeat timeout.

For kube-apiserver, it's a horizontal service so losing a node is not interesting, just like any other webapp. Some (most) controllers are singletons, but they run on every control plane node and use kube-apiserver for leader elections so as with Etcd, if the leader dies then a few seconds later another copy will get the leader lock and take over.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. My question was about the impact on workload of the only master node going down with the internal etcd.

Comment: There is no impact on a running workload, even in a complete failure of every control plane service all existing workloads keep on trucking.